# I have a z-index issue with I think may need a clip or something to fix

Tags: html, css, z-index

From this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vbaWK/3/, how can I make the fixed overlayed black rectangle appear over the blue rectangle, where they both overlap while scrolling the body.  There is an added rule though, whereever there is no overlap, it should be over everything, including the overlay.  Thanks.

html:

```
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

css:

```
.black
{
    background: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.blue
{
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 2000px;
    z-index: 4;
    position: relative;
}

.green
{
    background: green;
    width:100px;
    height: 2000px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}

.overlay
{
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:3;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Sorry I forgot to mention that when the blue rectangle is not overlapping, it should be over the overlay. There is a conflict.

Comment: Wouldn't setting the zindex on .black to anything higher than 4 do this?

Comment: if i set the rectangle higher to 4, then the overlay will be under the black rectangle.

Comment: So set the zindex on the black div to 5 and 6 on the overlay.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that there is a restriction, wherever there is no overlap, the blue rectangle or green should be on top of the overlay. however where there is overlap, it should be under both the overlay and the black rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Give the black rectangle the highest possible z-index, something like this:

```
.black
{
    background: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: if i give the black rectangle to 999, then it will be over the overlay, the black rectangle needs to be under the overlay.